# Does python have hooks into EXT3

Tags: python, linux, ext3

We have several cron jobs that ftp proxy logs to a centralized server. These files can be rather large and take some time to transfer. Part of the requirement of this project is to provide a logging mechanism in which we log the success or failure of these transfers. This is simple enough.

My question is, is there a way to check if a file is currently being written to? My first solution was to just check the file size twice within a given timeframe and check the file size. But a co-worker said that there may be able to hook into the EXT3 file system via python and check the attributes to see if the file is currently being appended to. My Google-Fu came up empty.

Is there a module for EXT3 or something else that would allow me to check the state of a file? The server is running Fedora Core 9 with EXT3 file system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

no need for ext3-specific hooks; just check `lsof`, or more exactly, `/proc/<pid>/fd/*` and `/proc/<pid>/fdinfo/*` (that's where `lsof` gets it's info, AFAICT).  There you can check if the file is open, if it's writeable, and the 'cursor' position.

That's not the whole picture; but any more is done in processpace by stdlib on the writing process, as most writes are buffered and the kernel only sees bigger chunks of data, so any 'ext3-aware' monitor wouldn't get that either.

Comment: Wow, my Linux-Fu is off today, never thought about taking that route. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

There's no ext3 hooks to check what you'd want directly.

- I suppose you could dig through the source code of [Fuser](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fuser) linux command, replicate the part that finds which process owns a file, and watch that resource. When noone longer has the file opened, it's done transferring.

Another approach:

- Your cron jobs should tell that they're finished.

We have our cron jobs that transport files just write an empty *filename.finished* after it's transferred the *filename*. Another approach is to transfer them to a temporary filename, e.g. *filename.part* and then rename it to *filename* Renaming is atomic. In both cases you check repeatedly until the presence of *filename* or *filename.finished*

Comment: if the "copy to temp, then rename" strategy is possible, by all means to it.  it's far easier to check, easier to cleanup, gentler with hardlink-based 'snapshots' (like rsnapshot), and a lot less likely to messup the filesystem even in catastrophic hardware failure.